# scheduleAtFixedRate not executing after first run

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have a scheduled executor to reset a parameter to 0 and awake all active threads to continue processing. However after initial run of the thread it is not executing again.

```
ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            logger.info("Setting hourly limit record count back to 0 to continue processing");
            lines = 0;
            executor.notifyAll();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return;
        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

There is another Executor defined in the class which executes further processes and not sure if this influences it:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for (String processList : processFiles) {

        String appName = processList.substring(0,processList.indexOf("-"));
        String scope = processList.substring(processList.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);

        logger.info("Starting execution of thread for app " + appName + " under scope: " + scope);
        try {
            File processedFile = new File(ConfigurationReader.processedDirectory + appName + "-" + scope + ".csv");
            processedFile.createNewFile();
            executor.execute(new APIInitialisation(appName,processedFile.length(),scope));
        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of interrupting the executor thread?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the documentation for `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-):

> If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed.

So something in your task is throwing an exception. I would guess the call to `executor.notifyAll()` which [is documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll--) to throw an `IllegalMonitorStateException`:

> if the current thread is not the owner of this object's monitor.

Comment: Added if statement around the notifyAll action to ensure that there are current active threads stupid me!

Answer (score 3):

Your scheduled task will most probably end up in a uncaught `Exception`. Taken from the `JavaDoc` of `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate`

> If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent
>   executions are suppressed.

Because you are provoking a uncaught exception, all further executions are cancelled.